# How do I create a loop in Python?

Tags: python

How do I put this code into a loop?

```
EnterWord = input ("Please Enter your Word here: ")
Reverse = EnterWord [::-1]

if EnterWord.lower() == Reverse.lower():
    print ("Hurrah!!! You have just found a Palindrome")

else:
    print ("Oh, Come on! you can do this man...")
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Write `while True:` at the top

Comment: `Oh, Come on! you can do better than this`. How about showing us what you have tried? Have you read the python docs to learn how loops work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question shows little effort on the OP's part to resolve the issue they are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to loop it indefinitely simply add while True to the program:

```
while True:
    EnterWord = input ("Please Enter your Word here: ")
    Reverse = EnterWord [::-1]

    if EnterWord.lower() == Reverse.lower():
         print ("Hurrah!!! You have just found a Palindrome")
    else:
         print ("Oh, Come on! you can do this man...")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
while True:
   EnterWord = input ("Please Enter your Word here: ")
   Reverse = EnterWord [::-1]

   if EnterWord.lower() == Reverse.lower():
       print ("Hurrah!!! You have just found a Palindrome")
   else: 
       print ("Oh, Come on! you can do this man...")
```

Comment: Come on, add some code indentation!

Comment: It's very important to actually test and run your code before you post it in an answer.

Comment: Better now! And do like @MorganThrapp has said in future...

Comment: It is my first code-answer. Don't blame me for the formation error based on copy paste

Comment: You made the error, why shouldn't you take responsibility for it?

Comment: Okay, while true at the top gives a syntax error. I appreciate the help

Comment: Thanks anyways. At least you all are right.

Answer (score -3):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
EnterWord = input ("Please Enter your Word here: ")
Reverse = EnterWord [::-1]

while EnterWord.lower() != Reverse.lower():
    EnterWord = input ("Please Enter your Word here: ")
    Reverse = EnterWord [::-1]
    print ("Oh, Come on! you can do this man...")

print ("Hurrah!!! You have just found a Palindrome")
```

Comment: For the first non-palindrome, `"Oh, come on..."` is not printed, and for a palindrome entered after a non palindrome, `"Oh, come on..."` is printed.  The `print` call should be just after the `while`.

Comment: Okay, this is good. I added the print call just after the while and it gave me what i wanted. After finding a palindrome, can it loop back to the "please enter your word here" without going into an infinite loop? Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Yes, you'd just need to have some way for the user to exit the loop. So, you'd move the "Please Enter your Word here: " to the first line of the while loop and change your looping condition.